# glDrawRangeElements of GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP not working properly (using glMapBuffer)

Tags: c++, opengl

I am trying to render points from a VBO and a Element Buffer Object with glDrawRangeElements.

The VBO and EBO are instanciated like this:

```
    glGenBuffers(1, &vertex_buffer);
    glGenBuffers(1, &index_buffer);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertex_buffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertex_buffer_size, NULL, GL_STREAM_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0,3,GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (char*)(NULL));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, index_buffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, index_buffer_size, NULL, GL_STREAM_DRAW);
```

as you can see they do not have any "static" data.

I use glMapBuffer to populate the buffers and then I render them with glDrawRangeElements.

**Problem:**

Concretly, what I want to do is to make a terrain with Continuous LOD.
The code I use and posted majorly comes from Ranger Mk2 by Andras Balogh.

My problem is this: when I want to render the triangle strip, there seems to be a point on the 3 points of a triangle which is somewhere where it should not be.
For example,
this is what I get in wireframe mode -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCPqR.jpg

and this is what I get in point mode (Note the column that stretches up which is the points that are not well placed) -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/CF04p.jpg

Before you ask me to go to the post named "Rendering with glDrawRangeElements() not working properly", I wanted to let you know that I already went there.

**Code:**

So here is the render process:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertex_buffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, index_buffer);

glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

glVertexPointer(4, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

glDrawRangeElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, va_index, ia_index, GL_UNSIGNED_INT,  BUFFER_OFFSET(0));

glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
```

and just before I do this (pre_render function):

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertex_buffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, index_buffer);

vertex_array = (v4f*)(glMapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, GL_WRITE_ONLY));
index_array  = (u32*)(glMapBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, GL_WRITE_ONLY));

//[...] Populate the buffers

glUnmapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER);
glUnmapBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER);
```

PS: When I render the terrain like this:

```
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);
printf("%u %u\n", va_index, ia_index);
for(u32 i = 0; i < va_index; ++i){
    //if(i <= va_index)
        glVertex4fv(&vertex_array[i].x);
}
glEnd();
```

strangely it works (part of the triangles are not rendered though but that is another problem).

So my question is how can I make glDrawRangeElements function properly?

If you need any more information please ask, I will be glad to answer.

Edit: I use Qt Creator as IDE, with Mingw 4.8 on Windows 7. My Graphic card supports Opengl 4.4 (from Nvidia).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this is causing your problem, but I notice that you have a mixture of API calls for built-in vertex attributes and generic vertex attributes.

Calls like `glVertexAttribPointer`, `glEnableVertexAttribArray` and `glDisableVertexAttribArray` are used for generic vertex attributes.

Calls like `glVertexPointer`, `glEnableClientState` and `glDisableClientState` are used for built-in vertex attributes.

You need to decide which approach you want to use, and then use a consistent set of API calls for that approach. If you use the fixed rendering pipeline, you need to use the built-in attributes. If you write your own shaders with the compatibility profile, you can use either. If you use the core profile, you need to use generic vertex attributes.

This call also looks suspicious, since it specifies a size of 3, where the rest of your code suggests that you're using positions with 4 coordinates:

```
glVertexAttribPointer(0,3,GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (char*)(NULL));
```

Comment: The generic attribute **0** is guaranteed to alias to `glVertexPointer (...)` so it is possible to do what this code does, just not a particularly good idea in practice. Whether this should actually work is going to depend on the vertex shader used though.

Comment: Thanks :D. It was the glVertexAttribPointer(0,3,GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (char*)(NULL));that was in error. (PS: The glVertexPointer, ..., I added them because I wanted to test everything and see if it did anything)

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman: Can you give me a pointer to the specs for that? I read that claim before, but was never quite sure if it was true. From the OpenGL 3.3 (Compatibility Profile) spec, bottom of page 35: "There is no aliasing among generic attributes and conventional attributes. In other words, an application can set all MAX_VERTEX_ATTRIBS generic attributes and all conventional attributes without fear of one particular attribute overwriting the value of another attribute."

Comment: @RetoKoradi: Read the paragraph immediately before that. A command like `glVertexAttrib4fv (0, ...)` is completely equivalent to `glVertex4fv (...)`. The only way this behavior can be satisfied is if attribute 0 aliases to position. And in fact, this alias is observed in every compatibility implementation of OpenGL I have ever worked with. Granted, since immediate mode is removed in core, this behavior is not necessary outside of compatibility mode. Since setting attribute 0 creates a new vertex, it is impossible to ever overwrite anything thus not violating the following paragraph.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman: Interesting. The two statements seem to contradict each other. The part I quoted suggests that generic attribute 0 could be used without overwriting the value of a fixed attribute. While the part you quoted suggests that it's doing exactly that. There's also nothing I found that for example suggests that `glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)` and `glEnableVertexAttribArray(0)` are equivalent. I have seen differences in how vendor implementations behave if you mix some of these calls.

Comment: Sorry, running out of comment space... What you're saying makes sense for the `glVertex4fv` call. But what if buffers are used? Is there aliasing between `glVertexPointer` and `glVertexAttribPointer(0, ...)`?

Comment: @RetoKoradi: That is actually a bit of a grey area. Strangely, it has remained a grey area ever since the GL 2.0 spec. was first published ~10 years ago. Though I do not go around actively trying this, I know NV always honors that alias and I suspect any implementation that ever implemented ARB Vertex Program does also (because that alias is ***required*** by that extension). GLSL tries to get rid of these aliases, but other parts of the compatibility API require them.